# Download from links using python

Tags: python, request, urllib2, urllib, urllib3

I would like to download data from this [website](http://current.hydro.gov.hk/en/download.php).

I inspected the source code and found that it uses the following link format for downloading data.

```
url = 'http://current.hydro.gov.hk/en/download_csv.php?start_dt={}%20{}:00&end_dt={}%20{}:00&mode=Surface'
url_filled = url.format("2018-01-02", "00:00", "2018-01-02", "23:45")
```

Then I tried to use request to download the CSV data.

```
import requests
r = requests.get(url_filled)
```

But then I received error.

```
  TimeoutError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connection.py in _new_conn(self)
    140             conn = connection.create_connection(
--> 141                 (self.host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw)
    142 

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\util\connection.py in create_connection(address, timeout, source_address, socket_options)
     82     if err is not None:
---> 83         raise err
     84 

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\util\connection.py in create_connection(address, timeout, source_address, socket_options)
     72                 sock.bind(source_address)
---> 73             sock.connect(sa)
     74             return sock

TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

NewConnectionError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py in urlopen(self, method, url, body, headers, retries, redirect, assert_same_host, timeout, pool_timeout, release_conn, chunked, body_pos, **response_kw)
    599                                                   body=body, headers=headers,
--> 600                                                   chunked=chunked)
    601 

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py in _make_request(self, conn, method, url, timeout, chunked, **httplib_request_kw)
    355         else:
--> 356             conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
    357 

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py in request(self, method, url, body, headers)
   1106         """Send a complete request to the server."""
-> 1107         self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
   1108 

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py in _send_request(self, method, url, body, headers)
   1151             body = _encode(body, 'body')
-> 1152         self.endheaders(body)
   1153 

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py in endheaders(self, message_body)
   1102             raise CannotSendHeader()
-> 1103         self._send_output(message_body)
   1104 

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py in _send_output(self, message_body)
    933 
--> 934         self.send(msg)
    935         if message_body is not None:

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py in send(self, data)
    876             if self.auto_open:
--> 877                 self.connect()
    878             else:

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connection.py in connect(self)
    165     def connect(self):
--> 166         conn = self._new_conn()
    167         self._prepare_conn(conn)

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connection.py in _new_conn(self)
    149             raise NewConnectionError(
--> 150                 self, "Failed to establish a new connection: %s" % e)
    151 

NewConnectionError: <requests.packages.urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x00000000081F5D30>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

MaxRetryError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py in send(self, request, stream, timeout, verify, cert, proxies)
    437                     retries=self.max_retries,
--> 438                     timeout=timeout
    439                 )

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py in urlopen(self, method, url, body, headers, retries, redirect, assert_same_host, timeout, pool_timeout, release_conn, chunked, body_pos, **response_kw)
    648             retries = retries.increment(method, url, error=e, _pool=self,
--> 649                                         _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
    650             retries.sleep()

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\util\retry.py in increment(self, method, url, response, error, _pool, _stacktrace)
    387         if new_retry.is_exhausted():
--> 388             raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
    389 

MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='current.hydro.gov.hk', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: /en/download_csv.php?start_dt=2018-01-02%2000:00:00&end_dt=2018-01-02%2023:45:00&mode=Surface (Caused by NewConnectionError('<requests.packages.urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x00000000081F5D30>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond',))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ConnectionError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-39-ac5f4cccaa6a> in <module>()
----> 1 r = requests.get(url_filled)

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py in get(url, params, **kwargs)
     70 
     71     kwargs.setdefault('allow_redirects', True)
---> 72     return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
     73 
     74 

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py in request(method, url, **kwargs)
     56     # cases, and look like a memory leak in others.
     57     with sessions.Session() as session:
---> 58         return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
     59 
     60 

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py in request(self, method, url, params, data, headers, cookies, files, auth, timeout, allow_redirects, proxies, hooks, stream, verify, cert, json)
    516         }
    517         send_kwargs.update(settings)
--> 518         resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
    519 
    520         return resp

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py in send(self, request, **kwargs)
    637 
    638         # Send the request
--> 639         r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
    640 
    641         # Total elapsed time of the request (approximately)

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py in send(self, request, stream, timeout, verify, cert, proxies)
    500                 raise ProxyError(e, request=request)
    501 
--> 502             raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
    503 
    504         except ClosedPoolError as e:

ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='current.hydro.gov.hk', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: /en/download_csv.php?start_dt=2018-01-02%2000:00:00&end_dt=2018-01-02%2023:45:00&mode=Surface (Caused by NewConnectionError('<requests.packages.urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x00000000081F5D30>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond',))
```

When I try open the link in google chrome, it works. A dialog comes out and asks me the download location.

Anyone can help? Thanks

Comment: I belive this has already been asked and answered. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22676/how-do-i-download-a-file-over-http-using-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you going through a proxy server? If so you can look at the proxies section in http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/. I've tried your code and it works fine

Comment: I am doing this in my company. is it likely that there is a proxy server? I am not familiar with it

Comment: Check in your computers network settings or ask someone if they know the network's proxy information and read through the docs I linked. Not sure if this is the problem, but might help

Comment: I tried setup the proxy and it shows <Response [200]>. Does it mean it works?

Comment: That's it! Now use r.text  to get the body of the request

Comment: HTTP 200 is good, means all went right. You can see all the status codes https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes to have more insight into what the codes mean

Answer (score 0):

> The server of the webpage sends the packets of the file slowly. We need to take into account that. So, we can use the chunking mechanism of the `request.get`.

```
import requests

# url of the csv file
csv_url = 'http://current.hydro.gov.hk/en/download_csv.php?start_dt=' + \
          '2018-01-05%2000:00:00&end_dt=2018-01-06%2000:00:00&mode=Surface'

# sample csv filename
csv_filename = 'test.csv'

# use stream mode for chunking
csv_body = requests.get(csv_url, stream=True)
with open(csv_filename, 'wb') as fd:
    for chunk in csv_body.iter_content(chunk_size=1024):
        fd.write(chunk)
```